# Remove last chars when using "while"

Tags: python

I wrote a function in Python to sort my data into a dictionary syntax, but because I'm using `while`, there is a comma that I would like to remove to avoid having an invalid syntax.

For example with the following code:

```
file = open("test.txt","w", encoding="utf-8")
number = 0
while number < 5:
    file.write("some text" + ", ")
    number += 1
```

This will create test.txt with the following text inside:

```
some text, some text, some text, some text, some text,
```

I would like to remove the last ", " added by at the end to look like:

```
some text, some text, some text, some text, some text
```

Any idea?

Comment: One suggestion: construct the entire sentence first (using `.join` methods if it is a list or something) and write one sentence at a time. essentially, dont use the inner while loop, but instead construct and write a sentence at a time.

Comment: Remark: The script I actually is longer than the example I wrote above and includes several "if, elif, ...". This is way I'm looking for a simple way to just delete the very last chars of the file. One solution I have is to close() the file, re-open it and using  x = x[:-1] to delete the last chars, but I'm sure there is a better way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
file = open("test.txt","w", encoding="utf-8")
number = 0
list_to_add = []
while number < 5:
    list_to_add.append("some text") # you can append anything based_on iteration
    number += 1
file.write(','.join(list_to_add))
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `join`

```
text_to_write = 5 * ['the text']
file.write(', '.join(text_to_write))
```

Answer (score 1):

simply use a different command for the last element.

```
file = open("test.txt","w", encoding="utf-8")
number = 0
while number < 5:
    file.write("some text" + ", ")
    if(number == 4):
           file.write("some text") 
    number += 1
```

Comment: This would work without problem but as my actual "while" loop is much longer than the one above I would have to repeat twice the code.

Comment: well, you could use an `if` condition that is active in the last iteration of your algorithm. Below that condition you modify the `write` command

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do the same thing without while loop:

```
file = open("test.txt","w", encoding="utf-8")
file.write(", ".join(["some text"] * 5))
```

`", ".join([ ... ])` function joins multiple strings of text in a list using a seperator `,`, in your case that equals to:

```
In [1]: ", ".join(["some text"] * 5)
Out[1]: 'some text, some text, some text, some text, some text'
```